# ArcGIS Pro: Export file geodatabase feature class including JOINs and RELATEs

Tags: arcgis-pro, export, attribute-joins, esri-geodatabase, relates

**Question**: Is there an approach to export a *File Geodatabase Feature Class* with the content resulting from all of its JOINs and RELATEs with *File Geodatabase Tables* from the same Esri geodatabase file so no JOINs and no RELATEs are needed anymore? The type of product does not matter, i. e. it may be a table, Excel file etc.

**Background**: A *File Geodatabase Feature Class* (*FGFC*) is linked to some *File Geodatabase Tables* (*FGT*) by JOIN and to some other *FGT* by RELATE. The *FGFC* and all *FGT* are all in the same Esri geodatabase file `*.gdb`. I'd like to export the *FGFC* with the content which results from the JOINs and the RELATEs, i. e. as it is visible when I open the *FGFC* as a table from the Table of Content in ArcGIS Pro. However, all following export approaches return the *FGFC* with its own original content, i. e. without the result from the JOINs and/or RELATEs.

- [Approach 1](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002n000000): Right-click on *FGFC* in Table of Contents in ArcGIS Pro > Data > Export
  Features
- Approach 2: Right-click on *FGFC* in Table of Contents in ArcGIS Pro > Data > Export Table
- Approach 3: In ArcGIS Pro: Geoprocessing > Table to Excel *(actually known not to be the solution)*

Approach 1 & 2 deliver JOINs but not RELATEs. Approach 3 delivers none of both.

[Creating JOINs instead of RELATEs](https://community.esri.com/t5/geoprocessing-questions/export-out-related-features/m-p/353039#M12238) might be a valid approach. However, it is not appropriate for a large number of RELATEs.

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.0 (ArcGIS Pro 3.1 Patch [3.1.1])

Comment: You may try to create a view (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/create-database-view.htm) that display your data as you need then export this view.

Comment: Exporting geodata as an "Excel file" is likely to lose fields.

Comment: What kind of relate are you using 1-n, n-1, n-m ?

Comment: Sometimes it is required to flatten out the tables into one big table. In my case, this is due to the government agency wanting the data a certain way. [FelixIP's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/34531/felixip) answer above is exactly what I was after. Use the 'Make Query Table' tool, input your tables. Enter a 'Where' clause that matches up your primary with the foreign key and run that tool and volia, got what was needed.

Answer (score 2):

You should certainly be able to export your data with a **joined table**, what you are calling approach 1. Why approach 1 is failing for you I cannot say without further evidence as it works perfectly OK for me.

Regarding relates, what you ask makes no sense to me as a relate is a "virtual link" between datasets, used in my case to primarily pass selections through one table to another. There is nothing to export and if you start thinking about it what happens if you have one-to-many relationship where thousands of features has millions of related records, you'll suddenly have billions of records! Not even the mighty Excel will be able to deal with that.

If you want to create a new dataset with vast amounts of unusable repetition in data created by relationships you need to explore python and using cursors to construct your dataset, i.e. turn those virtual links to table records.

Comment: The question is edited for the outcome from Approach 1-3 for JOIN and RELATE specifically.

Comment: An export of results from RELATE makes sense as the full result from RELATE will be used for local data analysis with other softwares, education and for basic archiving. Possible large numbers of records is of course something to consider, however it should not decline the want to solve a technical question.

Comment: A relate is a "virtual link" there is nothing physical to export as you have in a join. Well that's my understanding. If you want to export what the relate allows you to see, the only way I know is using python and use cursors to make the link and manually write out the data, being aware that you could be spewing millions of records, depending upon what the data is.

Comment: @Hornbydd Make query table tool does that. It will create duplicates of parent table records joining them one by one to records from relate. Can be very handy